# upload file using ajax like facebook uploading

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is, I want to upload a csv file without pressing a submit button and I used ajax for that case. But now, their is something errors appear, and the error said fopen() Filename cannot be empty. But I already get the file value that I want, but the $_FILES[$fie]['tmp_name'] can't read this value. But if I attach the variable in an alert() they display the exact filename. This is my sample codes.

This is the html:

```
<form id="Form2">
 <input type="file" id="fie" />
</form>
```

this is the javascript:

```
<script style="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#Form2').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var sub = document.getElementById("fie").files[0].name;

            if($('#cat1').hasClass('show')){
            $('#cat1').hide();

            $('#cat2').html("<img src='pb1.gif' />");

            $.ajax({

                url:'uploading.php',
                action:'get',
                data: 'fie='+sub,
                success: function(data){

                    $('#cat2').html(data);

                }
            });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the Php:
uploading.php

```
<?php

    include("conn.php"); //assuming that connected to a database.

    if (isset($_GET['fie'])) { 

     echo "<script>alert('".$_GET['fie']."')</script>";//IN ALERT THEY EXECUTE THE EXACT VALUE OF THE FILE I INPUT
     $fie = $_GET['fie'];
    $file = $_FILES[$fie]['tmp_name']; //PROBLEM IS THIS. THEY CAN'T READ THE VALUE AND TELL THEIR IS NO FILE.
    $handle = fopen($file,'r') or die ('Cannot open file'); 
     fgets($handle);
    do { 
        if (isset($data[0])) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_numbers (numbers,cute) VALUES ('".addslashes($data[0])."','".addslashes($data[1])."')"); 
        } 
    }
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

    echo "Successful Upload~!";

}

?>
```

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I don't see `move_uploaded_file` anywhere so nothing is actually uploaded.

Comment: Why do you think that you even have `$_FILES` created? You just sent a file name to a php script, there is no file contents being sent. Did you find this example online or did you create this yourself?

Comment: why not use a jquery plugin to upload http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: I create thi by my self. Just want to know the flow of uploading file without clicking a submit button.

Comment: @JuanCarlosAduan Here, visit this page on the subject http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: How about you take a minute to figure out how file uploading works, then you can move on to figuring the rest of the problem? Obviously, there's something added to the form called `enctype`, and for file uploads to work it has to be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. That's using regular HTML forms. But you're using async JS to send data to your script. You have never read the file contents. You just sent the file NAME. Do you see the difference?

Comment: I forgot only to write that enctype. But I have that in my code. So sir. Is there a missing in my codes or wrong syntax?.

Comment: Could anyone fix the missing of my syntax?.